# Convert long datframe in R with each band being in one column to stars object with band as dimension

Tags: raster, r, sf, stars

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      x     y  band   val
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1  12.5  48.7     1     0
2  14.3  47.3     1     0
3  10.3  48.0     1     0
4  13.6  46.7     1     0
5  12.4  48.5     1     0
6  14.5  47.6     1     0
```

In the band column are four bands (red, green, blue and alpha). What I would like to do is to convert it to a stars object with the bands column being a dimension and the val column an attribute. I simply cant figure out how to do that.

`st_as_stars(df)` gives me that:

```
stars object with 2 dimensions and 2 attributes
attribute(s):
      Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
band     1    1.75    2.5  2.5    3.25    4 1480
val      0    0.00    0.0  0.0    0.00    0 1480
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point                                      values x/y
x    1 40     NA    NA     NA    NA [9.554126,9.569126),...,[17.02663,17.04663) [x]
y    1 38     NA    NA     NA    NA [49.00454,48.94454),...,[46.73454,46.60454) [y]
```

But I do not know how to bring the attribute back to a dimension...

Here is a sample dataset:)

```
structure(list(x = c(12.536626, 14.256626, 10.316626, 13.566626, 
12.401626, 14.506626, 13.026626, 15.946626, 10.911626, 9.576626, 
13.046626, 12.146626, 11.461626, 9.891626, 14.846626, 14.626626, 
10.226626, 16.631626, 12.616626, 16.881626, 13.251626, 14.246626, 
9.561626, 10.366626, 13.326626, 10.261626, 12.441626, 13.526626, 
16.146626, 17.036626, 13.636626, 15.751626, 17.016626, 13.956626, 
13.141626, 13.606626, 13.136626, 12.726626, 15.596626, 10.891626
), y = c(48.7045384, 47.2595384, 47.9645384, 46.6695384, 48.4945384, 
47.5895384, 48.7395384, 46.8445384, 47.0095384, 47.8445384, 48.7695384, 
46.8695384, 48.0645384, 48.6495384, 47.0195384, 48.7595384, 46.7995384, 
48.0545384, 46.7995384, 47.5645384, 46.9495384, 47.0295384, 48.9745384, 
47.7195384, 47.0345384, 47.6595384, 47.7095384, 47.1495384, 47.3995384, 
48.5995384, 47.0095384, 48.5845384, 47.5795384, 47.1745384, 48.8595384, 
47.1395384, 47.7745384, 47.4095384, 47.3795384, 48.9145384), 
    band = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), val = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is the `dims` argument

```r
data$band = c("red", "blue", "green", "alpha")[data$band]
r <- st_as_stars(data, dims = c("x", "y", "band"))
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641493/how-can-i-cast-a-data-frame-to-a-stars-object-with-a-time-dimension